# Filter a list of strings in powershell by a regex, then group and sort by one of the capture groups

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a way to filter a list of strings in powershell by a regex, then group and sort by one of the capture groups.

Imagine my list is like this:

```
bogus0
ACBXYZ-0000 hello
bogus1
ACBXYZ-0000 hello again
bogus2
ACBXYZ-0001 world
bogus3
ACBXYZ-0001 world
```

First i've done this:

```
$list | select-string "^(ACBXYZ-\d+)(.*)"
```

Which outputs

```
ACBXYZ-0000 hello
ACBXYZ-0000 hello again
ACBXYZ-0001 world
ACBXYZ-0001 world
```

Then i've done this:

```
$list | select-string "^(ACBXYZ-\d+)(.*)" | % { "$($_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value), $($_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value.Trim(' ,-'))" } | sort | group | select name
```

Which outputs

```
Name
----
ACBXYZ-0000, hello
ACBXYZ-0000, hello again
ACBXYZ-0001, world
```

But actually i would like to output this:

```
Name
----
ACBXYZ-0000, hello
ACBXYZ-0001, world
```

since the message after the number is nice to have but not really important.

Any ideas?

PS.: I was able to achieve that with a more complicated script, but i was looking for a one-liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answering and researching for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63407843/52598) question on SO, I believe I have a solution that's alligned to your original intent.

No doubt this can be shortened further <sub>(this [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/209557/96472) should sort that out)</sub> but this would work for what you have posted

```
 ? {$_ -match '^(ACBXYZ-\d+)'} | group {([Regex]::Match($_, [Regex]::new('^(ACBXYZ-\d+)'))).Value} | % {($_.group | sort le*)[0]}
```

[Try-it-online](https://tio.run/##dYw7D4IwGEV3fsU3YNoqENCNxdfs4mBUVFKlKSaVEh7BBPjtlaoh0egd7zn3prJiWR4zIdQMG@gseZm7yLDQfLnY7va22wU0lrp8Yu8nBsrpNeml8afkQSUzEfV48gcTaEBNoTZDsG@0uMSATvjtHaIRQW0n8EyWKdQ4WDPO7kffX2kTm6EFfZWwCn9NCSHOhoqS6Y9BtzdD53XVQC6zAgQbksA9toZSDw)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a hash table to store your results. A hash table is a collection of key-value pairs. In your case, the keys will be the "ACBXYZ-0000" strings, and the values will be "hello" strings. Keys in hash tables are unique, which is exactly what we need here.

For example:

```
$myHash = @{}
$myHash["ACBXYZ-0001"] = "hi there"  # set a value
Write-Output $myHash["ACBXYZ-0001"]  # retrieve the value
```

I've rewritten your script to use a hash table here:

```
$list = gc text.txt
$out = @{}
$list | select-string "^(ACBXYZ-\d+)(.*)" | 
    % { $out[$_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value] = $_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value.Trim(' ,-') }
$out
```

That gives this:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                           
----                           -----                                                                                                           
ACBXYZ-0000                    hello again                                                                                                     
ACBXYZ-0001                    world
```

You can see that the second "ACBXYZ-0000" has overwritten the first. If you don't like that, you can check before storing a key to see if it exists in the hash table already with `$out.ContainsKey()`.

I'll leave it to you to work out how to output the results as a sorted list of strings. Let me know if you have problems.

Just for fun, I also rewrote your script to more to how I would do it:

```
$list = gc text.txt
$out = @{}
$list | % {
    if ($_ -match "^(ACBXYZ-\d+)(.*)") 
    { 
        $out[$matches[1]] = $matches[2].Trim(' ,-') 
    } 
}
$out
```