# Filtering a CSV and adding a new tag column in powershell

Tags: powershell, sed, csv, awk

I have a CSV-file `in.txt` with 3 columns (`Doc_Title`, `Doc_Date`, `Doc_URL`) and I want to use PS to add another column `Doc_Category` using another CSV-file `tag.txt` with 2 columns (`keyword`, `tag`). I already have a pipe in Powershell which creates the `in.txt` and I am now wondering how to solve this the easiest way. In Linux, I could use a combination of [sed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sed) and [awk](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/awk) to do that, but what is the power-shell way of doing it?

Sample `in.txt` could be (displayed as TSV for readability):

```
/pub/howto.en.pdf 1980-01-01 An easy introduction
/pub/howto.de.pdf 1980-01-01 Eine einfache Einführung
/pub/howto.fr.pdf 1980-01-01 Une introduction simple
/lit/intro.en.pdf 1980-01-01 Literature review
/lit/intro.pdf    1980-01-01 Revue de littérature
/foo/intro.pdf    1980-01-01 Literatur-Review
```

With the following tag definitions `tag.txt` (again displayed with fixed width for readability):

```
pub      Publication
lit      Literature
.en.pdf  English
.fr.pdf  French
.de.pdf  German
```

I would like to obtain

```
/pub/howto.en.pdf 1980-01-01 An easy introduction       Publication, English
/pub/howto.de.pdf 1980-01-01 Eine einfache Einführung   Publication, German
/pub/howto.fr.pdf 1980-01-01 Une introduction simple    Publication, French
/lit/intro.en.pdf 1980-01-01 Literature review          Literature, English
/lit/intro.pdf    1980-01-01 Revue de littérature       Literature
/foo/intro.pdf    1980-01-01 Literatur-Review
```

I am pretty lost how to achieve that in powershell, so any hint is warmly appreciated.

#### Related

- [Filter a list of strings in powershell by a regex, then group and sort by one of the capture groups](https://superuser.com/questions/1104161/filter-a-list-of-strings-in-powershell-by-a-regex-then-group-and-sort-by-one-of)
- [filtering CSV in Powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/1483890/filtering-csv-in-powershell)
- [Filter large CSV using MS powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/1319374/filter-large-csv-using-ms-powershell)

Comment: You specify colums as `Doc_Title`, `Doc_Date`, `Doc_URL` and then sample data as `/pub/howto.en.pdf 1980-01-01 An easy introduction`. Looks like Title & URL need to be swapped in one specification or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

Assume you have a file named in.txt located at path/to/in.txt, that contains the following:

```
"Doc_Title","Doc_Date","Doc_URL"
"/pub/howto.en.pdf","1980-01-01","An easy introduction"
"/pub/howto.de.pdf","1980-01-01","Eine einfache Einführung"
"/pub/howto.fr.pdf","1980-01-01","Une introduction simple"
"/lit/intro.en.pdf","1980-01-01","Literature review"
"/lit/intro.pdf","1980-01-01","Revue de littérature"
"/foo/intro.pdf","1980-01-01","Literatur-Review"
```

And you want to export the result to a .csv file located at path/to/out.csv, you can use this code:

```
$types=@{'pub'='Publication';'lit'='Literature'}
$languages=@{'.en.pdf'='English';'.fr.pdf'='French';'.de.pdf'='German'}
$rows=import-csv "path/to/in.txt"
$table=foreach ($row in $rows) {
    $title=$row.Doc_Title
    $date=$row.Doc_Date
    $url=$row.Doc_URL
    $type=($title | Select-String -pattern "(?<=\/)([\w]{3})(?=\/)").matches.value
    $type=$types.$type
    $language=($title | Select-String -pattern "(\.\w{2}\.pdf)").matches.value
    $language=$languages.$language
    [PSCustomObject]@{Doc_Title=$title;Doc_Date=$date;Doc_URL=$url;Doc_Type=$type;Doc_Lang=$language}
}
$table | export-csv "path/to/out.csv"
```

Please be sure to try my code and tell me if this gives the result you want or not.

My code is very simple, very clear and readable. I think it is best for you to figure it out by yourself, so that you can fully understand it. I don't like spoon feeding.

Some notes:

1, I think it is best to keep the file extension consistent with the format of the content, even though it is plain text file, it is structured, not any .txt file, so I think it is best to make the extension of CSV files .csv...

2,  I think your idea of putting two values into one column is bad, CSV stands for comma separated values, the values are delimited by commas, so better not put commas into values and keep the two values as separate columns instead of one.

3, The regexes I had given you works well with the examples you had provided, the regex for type identification accepts exactly three word characters (letters and digits) between slashes, the regex for language identification accepts exactly two word characters between dots, tweak the regexes if needed.

---

Minimum PowerShell version requirement: unknown, however I have only tested my code on PowerShell 7.1.1, I don't know whether my code works on lower versions or not, but it is always good to use the latest software.

---

### ***Update***

If there are only three characters between the slashes in `Doc_Title`, you can use this to get the three letters between the slashes:

```
$title.substring(1,3)
```

This will only work if there are exactly three letters between the slashes (and the first slash is at the start of the field).

You can use this to get a string like `.en.pdf`

```
$title.substring(($title.length-7),7)
```

This will only work if two conditions are met: first there must be this string present in the `$title`, and there must be exactly two characters between the dots.

I have revised my code to generate the result you intended:

```
$types=@{'pub'='Publication';'lit'='Literature'}
$languages=@{'.en.pdf'='English';'.fr.pdf'='French';'.de.pdf'='German'}
$rows=import-csv "path/to/in.csv"
foreach ($row in $rows) {
    $title=$row.Doc_Title
    $date=$row.Doc_Date
    $url=$row.Doc_URL
    $category=$types.$(($title | Select-String -pattern "(?<=\/)([\w]+)(?=\/)").matches.value)
    if ($title -match "(\.[\w]+\.pdf)"){$category=$category+","+$languages.$(($title | Select-String -pattern "(\.[\w]+\.pdf)").matches.value)}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Doc_Title=$title;Doc_Date=$date;Doc_URL=$url;Doc_Category=$category} | export-csv -path "path/to/out.csv" -NoTypeInformation -append
}
```

### ***Sample output:***

```
"Doc_Title","Doc_Date","Doc_URL","Doc_Category"
"/pub/howto.en.pdf","1980-01-01","An easy introduction","Publication,English"
"/pub/howto.de.pdf","1980-01-01","Eine einfache Einführung","Publication,German"
"/pub/howto.fr.pdf","1980-01-01","Une introduction simple","Publication,French"
"/lit/intro.en.pdf","1980-01-01","Literature review","Literature,English"
"/lit/intro.pdf","1980-01-01","Revue de littérature","Literature"
"/foo/intro.pdf","1980-01-01","Literatur-Review",
```

The regexes I use will match any number of word characters (a-zA-Z0-9_), they work well with the example you had given, but won't work if your string contains non-word characters, tweak as needed.

And why I didn't make a field with comma in the first place, refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

In short, the CSV file format is not fully standardized, there is no consensus regarding what a CSV should be like, different implementations of CSV may or may not allow commas in the fields, so the commas in fields may or may not be format-breaking.

Comment: Thanks for your lines. Your comment "you want to learn PowerShell, I will not explain it to you, I think it is best for you to figure it out by yourself, so you can fully understand it." confuses me. The code you wrote seems to be indeed PowerShell, I will try it asap and then accept your answer or write another comment.

Comment: To your point 2: The way you wrote `in.csv` is the actual format I have, I left out the quotes to make it easier to read. Having that this, the desired output format would also be `...,"English,Literature"` rather than `\t English, Literature` - what is wrong with having a string with all the tags inside?

Answer (score 1):

Just for grins, here's an alternative strategy for parsing the URL to obtain the tags:

```
$Tags = @'
id,text
pub,Publication
lit,Literature
en,English
fr,French
de,German
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | ForEach { $hash = @{} } {
    $hash.Add( $_.ID, $_.Text )
} { $hash }

@'
Doc_URL,Doc_Date,Doc_Title
/pub/howto.en.pdf,1980-01-01,An easy introduction
/pub/howto.de.pdf,1980-01-01,Eine einfache Einführung
/pub/howto.fr.pdf,1980-01-01,Une introduction simple
/lit/intro.en.pdf,1980-01-01,Literature review
/lit/intro.pdf,1980-01-01,Revue de littérature
/foo/intro.pdf,1980-01-01,Literatur-Review
'@ | ConvertFrom-CSV | ForEach {
    $Doc_Tags = @( $Tags[$_.Doc_URL.Split('/')[1]] , $Tags[$_.Doc_URL.Split('.')[-2]] ) -ne $null -join ', '
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Doc_URL'   = $_.Doc_URL
        'Doc_Date'  = $_.Doc_Date
        'Doc_Title' = $_.Doc_Title
        'Doc_Tags'  = $Doc_Tags
    }
} | Export-Csv $env:Temp\out.csv -NoTypeInformation
Import-Csv $env:Temp\out.csv
```

The `<*Here-String*> | ConvertFrom-Csv` construct can be replaced with `Import-Csv <FileName>` statements:

```
$TagFIle = c:\Tag.txt
$InFIle  = c:\In.txt

$Tags = Import-Csv $TagFIle | ForEach { $hash = @{} } {
    $hash.Add( $_.ID, $_.Text )
} { $hash }

Import-Csv $InFIle | ForEach {
    $Doc_Tags = @( $Tags[$_.Doc_URL.Split('/')[1]] , $Tags[$_.Doc_URL.Split('.')[-2]] ) -ne $null -join ', '
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Doc_URL'   = $_.Doc_URL
        'Doc_Date'  = $_.Doc_Date
        'Doc_Title' = $_.Doc_Title
        'Doc_Tags'  = $Doc_Tags
    }
} | Export-Csv $env:Temp\out.csv -NoTypeInformation
Import-Csv $env:Temp\out.csv
```

Comment: Your code is way too complex... Do you know the KISS principle?

Comment: I think splitting on delimiters is _less_ complex than regular expressions. I leverage the pipeline to minimize intermediate variables --- that's effecient. Tell me what confuses you & I'll be happy to explain it.

Comment: How about this? `j([char[]]"******" | %{[convert]::***($_)} | %{$_ -replace "??"} | %{($_ -split "(\w)"|?{$_ -ne ""}|%{[char]::***("$_",0).ToString("x")}) -join "" }) -join ","`

Comment: It is my code, can you crack it? I don't think so xD

Comment: No, the irony is sufficient. Now tell what part of my code has you confused.

Comment: I am not confused, I just think your code uses more characters than mine.

Comment: You are mistaken about character count as well when you compare your code (648 chars) with the second version of mine that reads from files (504 chars) as specifed by the OP. The version with the data inline is just to avoid creating sample data files. Furthermore, your hashtables are hard-coded! The code woulld have to be modified to add a new tag to the dictionary! Ever hear of separating code & data?  I always find it interesting to see different approaches to the same problem --- not sure why you took offense and went on the attack.